# App crashes while getting saved url from sharedPreferences

Tags: android

My register `button` calls my `register()` function through `Void doInBackground`. With this, my App crashes, but when using **URL** parameter as Static, defined in code, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
static void register(final Context context, final String regId, final String appName) {
    Log.i(TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
    SharedPreferences SERVER_URL = context.getSharedPreferences("URL" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "register.php";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);
    params.put("appName", appName); ...
}
```

Comment: how you stored url into preference? post that code.

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: I have Class PreferenceConnector, with function: `public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
  getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();

 }`

Comment: LogCat doesn't show any error. Just E -1

Comment: Likely: The `context` you're passing to the function is not a valid `Context`.

Comment: `context` at this moment is from PreferencesActivity with **this**

Comment: please add code of PreferenceConnector class

Comment: Is "serverUrl " display complete URL with register.php page in log??? And have you run that in browser?? If is it properly working???

Answer (score 0):

Here `SERVER_URL` is `SharedPreferences` instance from that we need to get specified value by using `getString()` method, try this,

```
static void register(final Context context, final String regId, final String appName) {
    Log.i(TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
    SharedPreferences SERVER_URL = context.getSharedPreferences("URL" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL.getString("replace_your_key_value",null) + "/register.php";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);
    params.put("appName", appName); ...
```

Comment: you may miss `/`, check my edit, i added that before `register.php`.

Comment: No I don't, because in sharedPrefs I saved url with `/`

Comment: check whether your preference name key name is correct? or else post your current code

Comment: When I printOut on TextView from sharedPrefs, with function: `SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("URL" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    String serverUrl = prefs.getString("URL") + /"register.php";
Log.i("Server URL " + serverUrl );
```

instead of in your code.

```
SharedPreferences SERVER_URL = context.getSharedPreferences("URL" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "register.php";
```

Comment: Tried, Your example, doesn't work. I changed your code to: ` SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String serverUrl = prefs.getString("url", null) + "register.php";` and no result.